# C interface: does failwith() leak memory?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to work with a C interface generated using camlidl.  The library I'm working with returns an error code by allocating and filling an in/out argument `char* error_message` and returning it.  After the function call, I check the error code for non-zero... if true, I call `caml_failwith(error_message)` to throw an OCaml exception using the library error message.

However, I started digging a bit, because throwing the exception looks as though it will terminate the function and never free the error message.  Consider this mock code:

```c
/* in the C stub function call... */
double _res;
int error = 0;
char* error_message = NULL;

// if this function errors, it will set error to non-zero
//  and strdup something into error_message
_res = call_library_function(&error, error_message);

if (error) {
  caml_failwith(error_message);
  free(error_message); // NEVER CALLED?
}

/* code to copy result to an OCaml value and return */
```

The exception func `caml_failwith(s)` implementation is in `runtime/fail_*.c`, but it basically just calls `caml_raise_with_string`, which is:

```c
CAMLparam1(tag);
value v_msg = caml_copy_string(msg);
caml_raise_with_arg(tag, v_msg);
CAMLnoreturn;
```

So, it copies the string to the OCaml value with caml_copy_string, and then raises the arg and no-returns.  In short, **error_message is lost**.

...Right?  What am I missing here... I could use canned strings but that makes dynamic error messages impossible.  I could maybe use static char*, though it's not thread safe any more without a bunch of work.  **Is there any way to call `caml_failwith`, using a plain old dynamic `char*`, and not have it cause a leak?**

---

EDIT: I thought of one solution...

```c
char error_message_buf[100] = {'\0'};
double _res;

// ... rest of local vars and service call ...

if (error) {
  strncpy(error_message_buf, error_message, 99)
  free(error_message);
  caml_failwith(error_message_buf);
}
```

... but man that's ugly.  `strncpy` to the stack just to turn around and `caml_copy_string` again?  Plus, it sets a hardcoded cap on error message length.  Still, if it's the only way not to leak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`caml_failwith()` is designed so you can call it with a constant string, which is a very common case:

```
caml_failwith("float_of_string");
```

So, you can't expect it to free its argument.

I don't personally consider this a space leak, it's just how the function is designed.

Your solution of copying the message first seems reasonable (and not particularly ugly) to me.

(This, in essence, is why I switched from C to OCaml many years ago.)